# ASP.NET MVC OutputCache inherited is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache

Hello I am trying using the OutputCache inheriting a base controller. But it is not working, my codes:

BaseController

```
 public abstract partial class BasicControllerController : Controller
{

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=60)]
public class SamplesController : BasicControllerController
{
    public ActionResult AgendamentoEmail()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
@System.DateTime.Now
```

But just not working.
It only works if I did not inherit, or I remove the code below the base controller

```
public abstract partial class BasicControllerController : Controller
{
    //protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    //{
    //    if (requestContext == null)
    //    {
    //        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    //    }
    //    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    //}

}
```

I think I have to do some implementation in protected override void Initialize.

Detail: I need this method, as there is variables that use other controllers

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this before and found that some pre existing Attributes cannot be inherited because they were designed that way in their declaration.

The only way that I found is to create a new attribute that extends the one you want to use but marked as Inherited, liked this:

```
[AttributeUsage (Inherited = True)]
public class InheritedOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
...
}
```

Comment: Helo.. tanks... I tried but it did not work ..  do you have any more detailed example?`[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All,Inherited=false)]
    public class DonutCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
    {
        public DonutCacheAttribute()
        {
            // get cache duration from web.config
            Duration = Settings.DonutCachingDuration;
        }
    }`

Comment: Inherited should be true, not false... did you try that?